# Google Maps 1.10.1 iOS with cocoapods giving duplicate symbol error

Tags: ios, cocoapods, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to integrate the new GoogleMaps sdk 1.10.1 and I followed the quick start from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

But I am getting the following error and i got stuck with duplicate symbol error.

```
GoogleMaps(ResourceContext.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN7gmscore8renderer14DepthMaskStateC1Eb in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(DepthMaskState.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN7gmscore8renderer14DepthMaskStateC2Eb in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(DepthMaskState.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN7gmscore8renderer14DepthMaskStateD0Ev in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(DepthMaskState.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN7gmscore8renderer14DepthMaskStateD1Ev in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(DepthMaskState.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN7gmscore8renderer14DepthMaskStateD2Ev in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(DepthMaskState.o)
duplicate symbol __ZNK7gmscore8renderer14DepthMaskState11StringValueEv in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(DepthMaskState.o)
duplicate symbol __ZNK7gmscore8renderer14DepthMaskState7PreDrawEPNS0_14EntityRendererERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS0_11EntityStateEEE in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(DepthMaskState.o)
duplicate symbol __ZNK7gmscore8renderer14DepthMaskState8PostDrawEPNS0_14EntityRendererERKNS_4base10reffed_ptrINS0_11EntityStateEEE in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(DepthMaskState.o)
duplicate symbol __ZTVN7gmscore8renderer14DepthMaskStateE in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(DepthMaskState.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN7gmscore8renderer15GLScopedContextC1EP15GMSIOSGLContext in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(GLScopedContext.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN7gmscore8renderer15GLScopedContextC2EP15GMSIOSGLContext in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(GLScopedContext.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN7gmscore8renderer15GLScopedContextD1Ev in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(GLScopedContext.o)
duplicate symbol __ZN7gmscore8renderer15GLScopedContextD2Ev in:
    /Users/klouddata/Documents/SVN_RIL/RTSS_iOS_B200/Pods/GoogleMaps/Frameworks/GoogleMaps.framework/GoogleMaps(GLScopedContext.o)
ld: 706 duplicate symbols for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Simple Solution
Go to Target ->Linking -> other linker Flag and add $(inherited) in other linker flag in both Debug and Release.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem and I have fixed it by removing `-all_load` from **Other Linker Flags** and I let CocoaPods to set my flags.

Check your project settings for this flag.

Comment: -all_load is inherited from Cocoapods flags... so how can I disable it?

Comment: @Kasas you can do this manually in files `Pods.debug.xcconfig` `Pods.release.xcconfig` (find `OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) ... -all_load ...` and remove it)

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed same problem with Xcode 6.2. No problem at all with Xcode 6.3.2
Workaround would be to use

```
pod 'GoogleMaps', '1.9.2'
```

which working fine for me (with Xcode 6.2)

Answer (score 1):

check your **Other Linker Flags** probably you have `$(inherited)` with other flag to GoogleMaps `-framework "GoogleMaps"`. I recommend set just `$(inherited)`

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem where there some other entries along with -ObjC in **Other Linker Flags**. Removing all other values except -ObjC solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Updating XCode to the latest version and using **$(inherited)** as **Other Linker Flags** option solved this problem for me.